# what does this.heroes inside of the .subscribe method refer to in angular's tutorial of heroes?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

So not much is said about this particular line of code inside of the tutorial itself:

```
getHeroes(): void {
  this.heroService.getHeroes()
      .subscribe(heroes => this.heroes = heroes) ;

}
```

From what I have seen, .subscribe retrieves "HEROES" from the hero.service method and passes it into the heroes parameter inside of the .subscribe method.

This is at least what I think is happening. Some peculiarities, if I console.log like this:

```
getHeroes(): void {
  this.heroService.getHeroes()
      .subscribe(heroes => console.log(this.heroes )) ;

}
```

I get an undefined for "this.heroes"

however, if I console.log like this:

```
.subscribe(heroes => console.log(this.heroes = heroes))
```

I get an output of the array that it is calling:

```
(10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 11, name: "Dr Nice"}
1: {id: 12, name: "Narco"}
2: {id: 13, name: "Bombasto"}
3: {id: 14, name: "Celeritas"}
4: {id: 15, name: "Magneta"}
5: {id: 16, name: "RubberMan"}
6: {id: 17, name: "Dynama"}
7: {id: 18, name: "Dr IQ"}
8: {id: 19, name: "Magma"}
9: {id: 20, name: "Tornado"}
```

Even more peculiar, if I console.log this.heroes outside of the .subscribe method, I get a list of the heroes as a well, like so:

```
getHeroes(): void {
  this.heroService.getHeroes()
      .subscribe(heroes => this.heroes = heroes),
      console.log(this.heroes) ;

}
```

which outputs:

```
(10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 11, name: "Dr Nice"}
1: {id: 12, name: "Narco"}
2: {id: 13, name: "Bombasto"}
3: {id: 14, name: "Celeritas"}
4: {id: 15, name: "Magneta"}
5: {id: 16, name: "RubberMan"}
6: {id: 17, name: "Dynama"}
7: {id: 18, name: "Dr IQ"}
8: {id: 19, name: "Magma"}
9: {id: 20, name: "Tornado"}
```

So my question is, what is happening to heroes inside of the subscribe method? Is it returning the list from the service and then passing it to the heroes parameter inside of the subscribe method?

For further reference to where I am at on the tutorial: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#subscribe-in-heroescomponent

One more thing to add, I thought that "heroes" was being set to the heroes:Hero[] array in the code, but it is not:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HeroService } from '../hero.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-heroes',
  templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
})
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {

  heroes: Hero[];

selectedHero: Hero;

onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
  this.selectedHero = hero;
}

getHeroes(): void {
  this.heroService.getHeroes()
      .subscribe(heroes => this.heroes = heroes),
      console.log(this.heroes) ;

}




  constructor(private heroService : HeroService) {



   }

  ngOnInit() { 
    this.getHeroes();
  }

}
```

If I delete

```
heroes: Hero[];
```

from inside of the heroes.component, I still get a list of heroes to display. So this.heroes is not binding to heroes: Hero[]

live example: https://stackblitz.com/angular/aaldojlqqlvd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fheroes%2Fheroes.component.ts

Answer (score 3):

It's important to view the whole `heroes.component.ts` as you can see there is an array called `heroes` defined at the top. So what the function is doing is setting the `heroes` array defined in the component to the `heroes` array that is returned by the service. With new names it could be like this:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    import { Hero } from '../hero';
    import { HeroService } from '../hero.service';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-heroes',
      templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
    })
    export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {

      selectedHero: Hero;

      heroesInComponent: Hero[]; // <<<< changed

      constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.getHeroes();
      }

      onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
        this.selectedHero = hero;
      }

      getHeroes(): void {
        this.heroService.getHeroes()
            .subscribe(heroesFromService=> this.heroesInComponent = heroesFromService); // <<<< changed
      }
    }
```

The reason why your snippet logs undefined is because `heroesInComponent` is still undefined because you haven't assigned a value to it (e.g. `heroesFromService`)

```
getHeroes(): void {
  this.heroService.getHeroes()
      .subscribe(heroes => console.log(this.heroesInComponent)) ;
}
```

The reason why this snippet logs the correct result is because the `=` (assignment) operator returns the resulting array after assigning.

```
.subscribe(heroes => console.log(this.heroesInComponent = heroesFromService))
```

Comment: That is what I thought initially too, but that is not what is happening. I deleted heroes:Hero[]; and I am still getting a display of the heroes list. This is what confused me initially.

Comment: Are you sure you saved and rebuild after deleting `heroes: Hero[]`? Because it should fail to build :p

Comment: Yes I am positive. Go to the live example and try it yourself: https://stackblitz.com/angular/aaldojlqqlvd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fheroes%2Fheroes.component.ts

This is what is so confusing, the heroes are still getting displayed despite deleting heroes:Hero[]

Comment: You can delete entirely the heroes In Component, assign this.heroes = heroes, and you will still get the heroes to display and a console.log of (this.heroes) once it has been assigned. So what I think is happening is that you are assigning this.heroes to the parameter of the .subscribe method and not at all to the heroes in the component.

Comment: Hmm, it's stackblitz that allows you to bind to variables that don't exist, because I tried running the project locally after deleting the `heroes: Hero[]`line and it fails to compile. `ERROR in app/heroes/heroes.component.ts(30,28): error TS2339: Property 'heroes' does not exist on type 'HeroesComponent'.`. So stackblitz just let's you bind undefined variables to values.

Comment: I ran it locally and it still worked so something strange is going on. Perhaps heroes is not binding to the heroes:Hero[] and is instead binding to the parameter in the subsbribe method?

Comment: What I thought it may be doing is returning the HEROES from the service, then adding that as an object array into the parameter of .subscribe

Comment: No, that's not happening because then your template wouldn't be able to do it's `*ngFor` over the `heroes` property of the component.

Comment: If you change the .subscribe method to any other name, say "h", .subscribe(h=> this.h = h) and then change your ngFor to "h" as well, it will still display the list without creating a type Hero[] in the heroes component. So I have no idea how it is binding without Hero[] in the heroes component.

Comment: I even tried modifying heroes in the heroes component to heroes: number; and it still displays! So it is getting the object from another place. It cannot be the heroes component.

Comment: It just makes no sense to me at the moment. Stackblitz shouldn't allow it to run. Maybe someone else can chime in with an explanation.